# Swift: connect a static button with a static method

Tags: swift

Say I have a static button member variable, as well as a static method which handles its click. How can I connect the button with the method? I couldn't figure out how to get `addTarget` to work in this case:

```
private static let my_button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    ...
    button.addTarget(???, action: #selector(handleButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

private static func handleButtonClick() {
    ...
}
```

Could I put `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController` in place of `???`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Details

xCode 8.2.1, Swift 3

### Full sample

```
import UIKit

class Button:NSObject {

    class func createButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 40)
        button.setTitle("Text", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Button.handleButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }

    class func handleButtonClick() {
        print("Click")
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.addSubview(Button.createButton())
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an actual object - an instance of your class - as the button's target. It might be possible to pass the class object, but that's not how it's supposed to work. The button basically expects its target to be an object that inherits from `NSResponder`.